# LINQ, динамическое формирование запроса в зависимости от количества фильтров поиска

Tags: c#, linq

Имею 6 значений по которым необходимо фильтровать данные:

1. дата с/ф
2. номер с/ф
3. поставщик
4. получатель
5. исполнитель
6. тин компании

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На стороне сервера получаю string[] с этими значениями. Если крыжик стоит над полем, то параметр участвует в фильтрации и наоборот.
Как сформировать LINQ запрос который бы при отсутствии параметра в string[] не учитывал его в фильтрации данных и наоборот.

```
var MySelect = from q in MyDB ...???
```

Comment: Немного не по теме вопроса, но не могу пройти мимо. *"Счет-фактура"*  во множественном числе пишется как *"счета-фактуры"*, а не *"счета фактур"* :)

Comment: Отличное замечание! Но, все же, мне больше интересует LINQ запрос.

Comment: А про запрос я вам уже ответил.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
var q = from row in ...
        ...
        select row; // Базовый запрос без фильтров

if (фильтр 1 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 1);

if (фильтр 2 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 2);

if (фильтр 3 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 3);

if (фильтр 4 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 4);

if (фильтр 5 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 5);

if (фильтр 6 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 6);

if (фильтр 7 установлен)
    q = q.Where(row => условие фильтра 7);
```

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, что базовый запрос без фильтров загрузит всю базу данных, а потом уже `Where` будет выполняться над загруженной в память коллекцией?

Comment: Нет, неправильно. Пока тип выражения остается `IQueryable<...>` - реально ничего происходить не будет, будет лишь накапливаться выражение запроса.

Comment: Вот когда вы вызовите, например, `ToList` - тогда уже запрос пойдет в БД. Со всеми накопленными условиями.

Comment: А если я выбрал фильтр 1,2,6? Ваша схема подразумевает перечисление всех вариантов запросов. По моему это факториал. Факториал от 6 = 720. Итого 720 запросов! Поправьте если не прав.

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC, это схема подразумевает то, что Вы спрашиваете. Будут установлены ровно те фильтры, что нужны. Никаких факториалов тут нет

Comment: Допустим в SQL я мог создать запрос в виде строки declare nvarchar(max) myselect = "базовая часть запроса" + "фильтры поиска" и выполнить его exec(myselect). А как в LINQ такое проделать?

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC А у меня разве не то же самое написано, с поправкой на типизированность?

Comment: Тоже самое но с одним большим но! Попробуйте написать все возможные запросы вашим методом с условием что фильтров теперь 7 и выбираются они рандомно! Там и поймете что мне не понравилось.

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC зачем?

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC расширил ответ до 7ми фильтров, раз вы так боитесь этого числа.

Comment: Тогда еще один вопрос. Если я в конце напишу var trololo =  q.ToList выполнится один запрос или 7?

Comment: @ArtemiyMVC да, разумеется. Как их может выполниться 7, если вы вызываете `ToList()` 1 раз?

Comment: Рабочий день кончается. Завтра попробую и отпишусь.

Comment: Все получилось! вот тестовый результат "WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[IsDelete]) AND (N'email' = [Extent1].[UserEMail]) AND (N'12345' = [Extent1].[UserIIN]) AND (N'login' = [Extent1].[UserLogin])"